# Can you set the size of an element using getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that gets resized on the mouse enter event. I am wondering if its possible to resize it based on its height received from `getBoundingClientRect().height`.

This is what I've tried so far with variations of this but nothing seems to work

```
btn.onmouseover = function(){
    let h = this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    this.style.width = "100%"; 

    if(h != this.getBoundingClientRect().height)
    {
        this.getBoundingClientRect().height = h;
    }

    this.style.right = "4%";
}
```

What happens is the button resizes when the mouse is over the button due to the text inside of it being moved from two lines to one so I was wondering if there is a function call similar to getBoundingClientRect() where i can set the height of the button based on the height I get from `h`. This way the text inside the button being moved from 2 lines to one doesn't resize the whole button on mouseover.

Also setting the height from `h` to the style height of the button creates a weird offset so that's not really a viable solution for me in this scenario

Comment: if you think about it, `get` suggests, correctly, that you can't `set`

Comment: I realized that when i posted it lol but is there a function similar something like setBoundingClientRect() that could alter the size of the button?

Comment: no, you would use other properties (.style.???) to manipulate the element

Comment: ive tried setting the style.height equal to h and it works but does it in a way that it creates an offset so the button height isn't really the same

Comment: The height you receive is calculated based on several CSS properties. _Setting_ the height is ambiguous: do you want to just increase the height? Scale it? Make the border bigger? The padding? The margin?

Comment: because the button resizes smaller when the width is increased due to the text inside it I'm trying to keep the button size the same height when the width increases on mouseover so basically scale it proportionally to its original height before width increased

Comment: or even better is it possible to keep text from changing position on button resize ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by this code. You are checking if the height you just obtained from `getBoundingClientRect` is equal to the height from `getBoundingClientRect`, and of course it will always be. And no, you can't possibly change the size of something by updating the information in the size you got from calling `getBoundingClientRect`. Anyway, if you really want to do something in JS relating to hovering, you need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, not `mouseover`.

But actually, you should be able to do this entirely in CSS.

```css
button { width: 200px; height: 3em; }
button:hover { width: 400px; }
```

```html
<button>Hi, I'm a button with some pretty long text</button>
```

If you really want to handle the mouse events yourself, then

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  button.style.height = button.offsetHeight + 'px';
  button.style.width = '600px';
});
  
button.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  button.style.width = button.style.height = '';
});
```

```css
button { width: 240px; }
```

```html
<button>Button with some pretty long text which will wrap</button>
```

Comment: yes, but when there is text inside the element and the width is increased, the text will go from 2 lines to one line making the height shrink so i am checking if the height did shrink because text was resized then resize the button to the original height

Comment: Why not just fix the height to what you want it to be?

Comment: because i want the width to resize on mouseover and there are multiple elements that i am creating that I dont want to be that size, only the ones that get resized because the text changes from multiple lines to one